# Why does my code just show a slider an my JFrame? (Swing)

Tags: java, swing, graphics2d

Have a JPanel, called contentArea. In it, there is a JSlider and a Compontent to be drawn.

But when I run it, I just get the slider. No Component. Why?

My main:

```
    JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame();
    JPanel content = new JPanel();
    content.setLayout(new BoxLayout(content, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

    Component paintArea = new PaintingArea();
    JSlider slider = new JSlider();
    content.add(paintArea);
    content.add(slider);
    mainFrame.add(content);

    mainFrame.pack();
    mainFrame.setVisible(true);
```

My Painting class:

```
public class PaintingArea extends Component implements Paintable
{
    @Override
    public void paint (Graphics g)
    {
        if (g instanceof Graphics2D)
        {
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2.setColor(Color.red);
            g2.draw(new Line2D.Double(a.getX(), a.getY(), b.getX(), b.getY()));
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Your `PaintingArea` component doesn't have a preferred size, it will be (0*0) by default .

Comment: Thank you. Have added a prefered Size, but still cant see a line.

Comment: Also check the coordinates for drawing your line, they may be out of bounds. Your code worked for me by calling `paintArea.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));` and drawing a `new Line2D.Double(10, 10, 100, 100)` for instance.

Comment: Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for working examples to get you started.